# HTML5 input: Whole number step with decimal min

Tags: html, forms, validation, input

I have an HTML5 number input with a min of `0.01` and a step of `any`. But for the user, the first "step" is 0.01, and subsequent steps include ".01".

I want to enforce a minimum value of 0.01 while allowing the user to step in whole numbers (i.e., 1, 2, 3, etc.).

How is this possible?

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what the issue is here. Can you elaborate and show what values you want and don't want?

Comment: @j08691 OP wants to enforce a minimum value of 0.01 but wants to step in whole numbers. When setting `min="0.01"` and `step="any"` it'll step to 1.01, 2.01, 3.01, etc. He instead wants to step right to 1, 2, 3, etc.

Comment: Ah thanks @AndréDion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're going to have to use JavaScript. With jQuery it would be:

```
$('input').on('change', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.val() < 0.01) {
    $this.val('0.01');
  }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyWalkerDesign/hkdbm3xh/)

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: I would just clarify that the input's "min" attribute would have to be removed for this to work.